# How to get the next row number in MS SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I would be grateful if someone could show me how in `SQL Server 2008` you can get the next free available row number in a database table?

What I am trying to do is implement something similar to `Oracle` where sequence numbers give the next number for a new row. Searching the internet, I haven't found anything that matches this, but what I have found is `row_number()`. Unfortunately, I cannot make it work within a `insert` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the [IDENTITY property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) for a column. Using that allows SQL Server to auto-assign what you're calling row numbers.

A quick example using `id` as an IDENTITY column:

```
DECLARE @MySampleTable TABLE (
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO @MySampleTable
    (name)
    VALUES ('Andy5'), ('Joe');

SELECT id, name
    FROM @MySampleTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @newId int;
SET @newId = 0;

select @newId = max(id) + 1
from my_table;

insert into my_table
values(@newId, ...)

... more code ...
```

Wrap the above code in a transaction and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want the row number or are you just looking for an ID.

In that case, look for identity columns and sql server.
http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article753-identity-columns-in-sql-server.aspx

or: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/autonumbering-identity-columns

In these cases, in your insert statement you do not specify the ID and sql server automatically provides a new one.

Succes

Comment: Not being too familiar with SQL Server 2008, as my experience is on Oracle and MySQL. So, I am glad of any help. I see both responses talk about IDENTIY, but as I already have a table with a datatype of int and a name, could on the INSERT something along the lines of INSERT TABLE A VALUES (IDENTITY (1,1), 'A', 'B'); ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up the identity field when you create the table. Then when you insert into it, you skip that field. An insert would be something like assuming the identity field is called table1id:

```
Insert table1 (field1,field2)
values('test','test2')
```

Now identity has some limitations. It will use up a number even if the action is rolled back or if the record is deleted it will not re-use it, so there will be gaps. That should not be important as a surrogate id shouldn't have business meaning anyway.

Comment: Is it possible to set identity through Entity Frameworks 4.0? We have tables created through through entity frameworks.

Comment: I don't know I would never allow anyone to create a table in an ORM. That's poor database design.